# Парсинг на базе pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

На вход мне приходит сроки типа: "1,2,3". Я ее разделяю на базе. Каждое значение я хочу проверить с таблицей `products` с полем `prd_code` и найти `count (*)`. У меня вибмвае ошибка. Помогите написать запрос

```
select COUNT(*) 
  from dual LEFT OUTER JOIN products on 
       (  select regexp_substr(trim('1,2,3'),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) from dual 
         connect by TRIM(regexp_substr(trim('1,2,3'),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)) is not null
        ) = prd_code 
        and prd_remove_date is not null;
```

Comment: А что тут dual делает ? Если вы хотите посчитать записи в products так в нем и считайте. а ваш подзапрос, парсящий строку можете непример в IN поместить, или в качестве подзапроса в from и сделать join с ним. и в любом случае, если вам count() нужен в разрезе чего либо, то у вас просто обязан быть group by по этому полю

Comment: Привидите пример данных и ожидаемый вывод запроса. Если у вас выдаёт ошибку, не стесняйтесь её опубликовать, она скорее всего напоминает вам, что вы where забыли. Если вы указывает метку plsql, то добавте в вопрос хотя бы одну строчку plsql-кода.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вы хотите именно для каждого приходящего значения посчитать, сколько раз оно встречается в таблице? Тогда лучше немного наоборот сделать:

```
with t as (select regexp_substr(trim('1,2,3'),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL) value from dual 
         connect by TRIM(regexp_substr(trim('1,2,3'),'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)) is not null)
select t.value, count(p.*)
  from t left join products p on t.value = p.prd_code 
                             and prd_remove_date is not null
 group by t.value
```